# Problema al crear un elemento (div) en js

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Como se puede crear y que meta dos artículos dentro cada div hasta que se acabe el bucle.

La idea es agrupar los artículos en un div.row cada 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). El ejemplo que has compartido no nos vale, deberías copiar y pegar el código en tu pregunta, y no compartir capturas de pantalla. Nos facilita mucho el trabajo de ayudarte.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿has probado a solucionarlo a nivel de CSS? Es decir: aparentemente quieres mostrar dos artículos (dentro o no de un`div`) por cada fila, eso podría conseguirse sin programar nada en PHP, del lado del cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Seria posible, pero tendrías que hacerlo en el bucle de WordPress usando PHP, ya que sería la forma mas viable de realizar, seria algo así:

```
if (have_posts()): 

$esPar = 1; // Creamos la variable, esPar y le asignamos el valor 1

// Iniciamos el bucle
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 


    if ( $isPar % 2 == 0) { 

        // Si el resto de la division entre 2 es 0, entonces es par
        // Tu Código Aquí
        echo 'Es Par';
        echo get_the_title();

    } else {

        // En caso de ser Impar
        // Tu Código Aquí
        echo 'Es Impar';
        echo get_the_title();

    }

$isPar++; // Incrementamos el valor de la variable
// Finalizamos el bucle
endwhile;
```

Esto verifica si el numero del post es par o impar y con eso puedes agregar un diseño personalizado en función de si es o no numero par.